# about builing qsqlmysql in qt

Tags: mysql, qt

there.

I want to create qsqlmysql.dll file using source code of qt.
but When I built the mysql project, qsqlmysql.dll file was not created
and other files were created as follows

[image]

The content of my mysql.pro file is as follows:

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql

HEADERS += $$PWD/qsql_mysql_p.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/qsql_mysql.cpp $$PWD/main.cpp

#QMAKE_USE += mysql

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../../../../../Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/lib/' -llibmysql
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../../../../../Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/lib/' -llibmysql
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../../../../../Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/include/'
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../../../../../Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C 6.1/include/'

OTHER_FILES += mysql.json

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QMYSQLDriverPlugin
include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

The following is the contents of the compile output window that appears when building.

```
20:46:56: Running steps for project mysql...
20:46:56: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
20:46:56: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release all
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug all
20:46:57: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" exited normally.
20:46:57: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

I would be grateful if you could tell me how to create the qsqlmysql.dll file
Thank you.